# Not operator in Regular expression for set of values

Tags: java, regex

I need to improve my skills on how regex is used in JAVA,

I want to basically search if a pattern is found in a string called input.
Now this input should return false to anything apart from WO.*

Like

```
WO.SYNC : true
WO.UPD : true
WO.REL : true

ACCOUNTS.SYNC : false
SC.SYNC : false
```

Below is the sample piece of code which I wanted to use,
What is to be done here?

```
Pattern p = Pattern.compile("^(WO.*)");
String input = "WO.SYNC";
Matcher m = p.matcher(input);
System.out.println(m.find());
```

Comment: This looks OK (although you don't need the group, and you don't need the `.*`; `"^WO"` would suffice as a pattern that tests whether a string starts with `WO`), so where's your problem?

Comment: What's exactly your problem?

Comment: For `SC.SYNC` is `false` and it's correct for this pattern. What is the problem?

Comment: According to your explanation, `SC.SYNC` should return false, not true...

Comment: Pattern p = Pattern.compile("^WO"); This is returning false "WO.SYNC"

Comment: @fge My mistake, Sorry for that. But yes SC.SYNC should return false

Comment: Are you sure?! Pattern p = Pattern.compile("^WO"); returns true for "WO.SYNC". even if the input = "WO1231.SYNC", it returns true.

Comment: your regex is working fine http://fiddle.re/wbezg check your question

Comment: Thanks @TimPietzcker. I was using find(). The error got resolved by replacing find() with matches(). Thanks so much.
Please find below comments under separate thread for the answer.

Comment: There shouldn't be any difference since your regex is using the `^` anchor to force `WO` to match at the start of the string, and `.*` matches everything else in the string. There must be something else that you haven't showed us in your code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Pattern p = Pattern.compile("^(?!ACCOUNTS).*$");

With this I could able to achieve the solution.

Answer (score 0):

First, I am not sure why "SC.SYNC" is return true. It seems that the return value is false. Second, matches() method should be invoked if you want to check if a string is available for a pattern.

Comment: But careful, the `.matches()` method always forces the *entire string* to match the regex.

Comment: Yeah, that depends on the use case to invoke which one

Comment: Thanks Tim Pietzcker. I was using find(). The error got resolved by replacing find() with matches(). Thanks so much.